# JAXB ignores @XmlAccessorFactory in package-info.java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization

We have written our own AccessorFactory to serialize our POJO in XML, so we have created package-info.java and added the annotation @XmlAccessorFactory in this file.

```
@XmlAccessorFactory(MeiAccessorFactory.class)
package com.meicpg.ti.domain;
```

All our POJO are annotated with @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE), and we have annotated all fields that have to be serialized with @XmlElement

Most of the time the serialization works well, but sometimes on dev's machine (in production we don't have this issue, and developer who works on Unix ) POJO aren't serialized.

I have tried to annotate one of the POJO with @XmlAccessorFactory, and it has been serialized correctly. On another POJO, I moved @XmlElement annotations on getters and it has been serialized correctly too.

Before to apply one of this solution on all my POJO, I would like to know if somebody has already met this weird behaviour and found why annotations in package-info.java are ignored.

Thanks.

Comment: `@XmlAccessorFactory` is a bit of an obscure JAXB RI extension, do you have a specific use case that requires this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I tried to add other annotations in package-info.java (like @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) because we use it in every POJO), and it seems that all annotations in package-info is ignored.

Any idea?

Comment: I have added an answer that should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314322/jaxb-ignores-xmlaccessorfactory-in-package-info-java/21318313#21318313

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add other annotations in package-info.java (like
>   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) because we use it in every POJO),
>   and it seems that all annotations in package-info is ignored. Any
>   idea?

If annotations in `package-info` are being ignored be sure of the following:

1. Your package annotations are defined in a file called `package-info.java`.
2. Your `package-info.java` source file is being compiled into `package-info.class`.
3. The `package-info` annotations will only apply to classes within that package.  You will not see them impact classes in other packages so you may need other `package-info` classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
All my package-info.java source files aren't compiled. It's a known issue for ant's version I'm using.